# How to install selenium for Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver

I have run the command `pip install selenium`, and it can execute `from selenium import webdriver` in terminal, but it cannot execute this line in Jupyter Notebook, which shows **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'"**. Besides, I also copied *chromedriver.exec* file into the path of my jupyter. Does anyone konw how to solve it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Anaconda navigator to run Jupyter then you need to run the `pip install selenium` command within the Anaconda prompt.

I believe that your Python environment in Jupyter differs from the Python environment that may be in your PATH.